# How do you mutate a relational field in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

Let's say you've got type Player and type PlayerSkills

```
type PlayerSkills {
  playerID: Player
  health: Int
  attack: Int
  defence: Int
}

type Player {
  playerID: ID!
  playerName: String
  balance: Int
  playerSkills: PlayerSkills
  inventory: [Item]
}
```

If you create a mutation to add a new player, how would you tell GraphQL a particular player is associated with a particular skill collection?

```
mutation (
  $playerID: ID!, 
  $playerName: String, 
  $balance: Int
  $playerSkills: PlayerPlayerSkillsRelation

) {
  createPlayer(data: {
    playerID: $playerID, 
    playerName: $playerName, 
    balance: $balance,
    playerSkills: $playerSkills
  }) {
    playerID
    playerName
    balance
    playerSkills {
      playerID
    }
  }
}
```

```
input PlayerPlayerSkillsRelation {
  create: PlayerSkillsInput
  connect: ID
  disconnect: Boolean
}

input PlayerSkillsInput {
  playerID: PlayerSkillsPlayerIDRelation
  health: Int
  attack: Int
  defence: Int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating the input part. Normally, when your mutations manipulate the same data as your queries, they end up being quite similar, if not the very same. Unless there are other requirements, I would arrange them this way:

```
mutation (
  $playerID: ID!, 
  $playerName: String, 
  $balance: Int
  $playerSkills: PlayerSkillsInput
) {
  createPlayer(data: {
    playerID: $playerID, 
    playerName: $playerName, 
    balance: $balance,
    playerSkills: $playerSkills
  }) {
    playerID
    playerName
    balance
    playerSkills {
      playerID
    }
  }
}

input PlayerSkillsInput {
  health: Int
  attack: Int
  defence: Int
}
```

Note that there is no `PlayerPlayerSkillsRelation`, nor a field `playerID` in `PlayerSkillsInput`. The input player just takes its skills and no relation to the player, because you can deduce that yourself in the implementing code. Only the player being created can posses those skills, so you don't really need extra input fields.

Not entirely sure about `connect` and `disconnect`, but those can easily be added to `PlayerSkillsInput` if you need.